# How to set logo in admin configuration tab in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, tabs, system-configuration

I want to add my company logo to my custom module configuration tab in admin.

Here is code of tab:

```
<tab id="mytab" translate="label" sortOrder="110">
    <label>My Label Here</label>
</tab>
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively add the image via css.

system.xml:

```
<tab id="mytab" translate="label" sortOrder="1000">
        <label>My Label Here</label>
        <class>my-tab</class>
 </tab>
```

your adminhtml.css

```
.config-nav .my-tab .admin__page-nav-title::before {
    content: '';
    background-image: url("../images/your_logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 30px;
    background-position: 0 0;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    top: 11px;
}

.config-nav .my-tab .admin__page-nav-title strong {
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: How i can add this css  in adminhtml by custom Module?

Comment: In Magento 2.4.1, you need to specify the class attribute in the tab node, like:
       `<tab id="mytab" translate="label" sortOrder="1000" class="my-tab"><label>My Label Here.net</label></tab>`

Answer (score 1):

You can set your logo url to tab label like this:

```
<tab id="mytab" translate="label" sortOrder="110">
    <label><![CDATA[<img src="http://logos-download.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Magento_logo.png" width="100px"/>]]></label>
</tab>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: How can I give the local media URL?

Comment: This doesn't work in Magento 2.3.3 onwards